# Specify language / framework on Heroku

Tags: php, node.js, heroku

I have a PHP app that happens to use gruntjs for some build automation. I was attempting to launch this project on heroku, however it believes this is a node.js project, and thus it won't launch. How can I specify to heroku that this is a PHP project?

Answer (score 0):

The PHP buildback is invoked if an `index.php` file is located in the repo root directory - see https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php/blob/master/bin/detect#L3